# Vertical Sliding Submenu is opening/closing quickly during a refresh, is this normal?

Tags: jquery, submenu

Please see current jsbin:

http://jsbin.com/AWahuXe/12/edit

Here is what is working:
1) Menus have their submenus closed until +/- button is clicked to open submenu.

Here is what needs help:
1) Once a submenu is clicked, the new page opens ok but all submenus quickly expand then collapse which looks unprofessional. How can I keep that quirky expansion/contraction from happening?

Here is a link to my website that help illustrate the expansion/contraction issue.
You can also see this by simply refreshing the page.

http://www.ceramictilepro.com/Ceramic-Tile-And-Grout-Tips_1.php

Any ideas would greatly be appreciated :)

Here is the full jQuery:`

```
 $.each([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], function (index) {
$(".toggle" + index).click(function () {
    $(".submenu" + index).slideToggle("fast", function () {
        // Animation complete.
    });
});
});

$(function () {
var split = window.location.pathname.split('/');
var mnurl = split[split.length - 1];
mnurl = 'Ceramic-Tile-And-Grout-Tips.php';
$(' a[href="' + mnurl + '"]').addClass("_current_highlight_button");
});

$(function () {
var selected;
$('.vmenu li a').click(function (e) {
    $('.vmenu ul').not($(this).parent().next('ul')).css('display', 'none');
});
$('a').each(function () {
    if ($(this).prop('href') == window.location.href) {
        $(this).addClass('_current_highlight_button');
        selected = $(this).parent().parent();
    }
});
$('.vmenu ul').not(selected).css('display', 'none');
});
```

`

Comment: have you tried using .hide() instead of css('display','none'). from jQuery docs (http://api.jquery.com/hide/) - "Note that .hide() is fired immediately and will override the animation queue if no duration or a duration of 0 is specified."

Comment: You might try setting the display to none in your css to start with instead of in your jquery.  I couldn't get it to stop showing sometimes when i hit run in jsbin, I even took out all the jquery and just had it hide the ul tags but still did the same thing. But it didn't have the same problem in jsfiddle i have no idea why. http://jsfiddle.net/matt9388/pWWg4/

Comment: Hi Maxim, I tried using ".hide(0)" to replace the ".css('display', 'none');" with no luck. here is the results live http://www.ceramictilepro.com/Ceramic-Tile-And-Grout-Tips.php

Comment: wondering if hiding the "submenu" would keep the submenu from expanding/collapsing on a page reload or refresh.

Comment: The submenus don't even work for me. When I click + the submenus drop down and then the entire thing disappears. Firefox V25.0. Sorry to throw some more bad news your way.

Comment: Nick, sounds like the .hide and/or 'display none' is causing that. not sure how to get around that issue but thanks for pointing it out :)